# How do I store a date and find how many days have passed since that date?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, date

I am creating an Android app that will calculate the interest on a loan. How do I store a date that is selected from a DatePicker, then calculate how many days have passed between the current date and the stored date?

Answer (score 1):

There's java.util.GregorianCalendar in the standard library, which you can initialise with the data from the DatePicker.

Alternatively, you could use JodaTime, which I'm informed provides a nicer library for dates and times (I've not actually given it a go myself, but it's definitely worth looking at).

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

As for calculating the number of days between two dates, JodaTime has the Days.daysBetween method, which makes it pretty simple. To use that it's probably simplest to store the two dates and times in LocalDate objects (though this assumes that you've not got any time zone issues to think about).

Comment: I'll look into Joda-Time, but as an external library will it play nicely with Android? I've been told that it's a bad thing to import a lot of external stuff.

Comment: Should be just fine. Importing external stuff isn't a bad thing outright. I'd only start to worry if you were bloating your download to the point where it was annoying to anyone installing it, and this is often outweighed by not having to reimplement functionality that's already out there in some library.

One thing to watch out for with JodaTime is that you may get some warnings if you take their compiled library and import it (as it converts the Java bytecode to Dalvik bytecode). I don't think these are an issue, but if you want to get rid of them, compile the JodaTime library for Java 1.5).